# How can I get the DOS variable %USERNAME% in PHP

Tags: php

I did many tests in order to catch in my php code the dos environment `%USERNAME%`, my operating system is Windows 7.

This will allow my `php` program to know the username currently logged in into a network.
Here some of the tests runned in both environment `Wamp` and `Xampp`. 
Any help please will be very appreciated.

```
<?php
    session_start();
    //1°test, not ok
    //echo "user=". $username;

    //2° test, not ok
    //echo 'My username is ' .$_ENV["USER"] . '!';

    //3°test in this case I get back "user-pc$" . It's not correct , the right username - logged in in Windows 7 operating system - is "user". 
    //infact I got "user" value running from command line "cmd" the "set username" command.
    $user_name = getenv('USERNAME');
    echo "username=".$user_name."<br>";

    // running phpinfo I see as USERNAME "user-pc$" but unfortunately this is not the right value
    phpinfo();
```

Comment: Basic problem here is that the result of anything like this will be based on the account that Apache is logged in as, And for wampserver or xampp that will be the `nt authority\system` and not `Valgo`

Comment: did my answer worked?

Answer (score 0):

i don't have a PHP/Windows system here to check this, but it should work:

```
$user_name = exec('echo %USERNAME%');
```

if that does not produce the expected output for reasons like RiggsFolly stated in comment:

> Basic problem here is that the result of anything like this will be based on the account that Apache is logged in as, And for wampserver or xampp that will be the `nt authority\system` and not `Valgo`

then you may wanna try getting the output of `query user` command, parse the data, and maybe do some filtering and/or deciding based on the `STATE` value what is the user you want. Don't forget there may be many users logged in, having "Active" state.

```
$data_to_parse = exec('query user');
```

Comment: Unfortunately no. $user_name is %MyPc$% where Mypc is the name of the pc.

Comment: @Valgo54 that's strange. if you open a command line in your windows system and do `echo %USERNAME%` does it produces output? oh wait a minute i just noticed RiggsFolly comment in your question. that's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Hello thanks for your advice.
Running $data_to_parse = exec('query user'); at home I get the following output 
"valgo console 1 Active nobody 24/04/2016 15:52"
where valgo is the name of the current user connected. Great! I'll try within the network and I let you know.

Answer (score 0):

I tested:
$data_to_parse = exec('query user');
and I got back 
gorlav rdp-tcp#0 1 Attivo . 26/04/2016 14:22
where "gorlav" is the name of the account connected.
Great. Many thanks

Comment: hello there, in that case you may wanna mark my answer as "accepted". if you wanna reply you can use the comments. don't post "answers" as a reply.